# In a Rails 3 controller how do i Grab the name of the radio button set that produced the answer?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been working on this problem for over 3 days. :=[

I am trying to pick up the values that are being passed from a jQuery. My code for the view, 
application.js and controller is as follows.

view:

```
<%= form_tag update_result_answers_path, :remote => true do %>
   <% @answers.each do |q| %>
      <%= q[0].question %>
      <% [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].each do |f| %>
         <%= radio_button_tag q[1].id, f, f == q[1].score, :class => 'submittable' %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

application.js:

```
$('.submittable').live
    ('change', function() 
        {
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
        return false;
        }
    );
```

controller:

```
  def update_result
    @answ = Answer.where(id = name)
    @answ.update_attributes params[:score]
  end
```

In the console window where the rails server is running i get the following when a radio button is clicked:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>..., "155"=>"2"}
```

I named the radio button set with the id of the answer record (see q[1].id in the view). So the name of the radio button set, which is also the id of the answer record, is "155". The answer is "2". Params[:id] doesn't capture the id so i changed to "@answ = Answer.where(id = name)" in the controller and get the following error:

```
"undefined local variable or method `name'"
```

How do i change the controller to grab the name of the radio button set and the value?

Thanks.

Comment: @Mike, why did you delete your answer? I was working with it and poof... it was gone :=]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest another level of nesting  - so that you can segregate your Answers from other form parameters coming in.

```
HTML

<%= form_tag update_result_answers_path, :remote => true do %>
  <% @answers.each do |q| %>
    <%= q[0].question %>
    <% [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].each do |f| %>
  <% if f == q[1].score
    chk="checked='checked'"
  else
    chk=""
  end %>

      <input "<%= chk %>" class="submittable" name="answer[<%=q[1].id%>]" type="radio" value="<%= f %>" />
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

RUBY

def update_result
  params[:answer].each_pair do |key,value|
    @ans = Answer.find(key.to_i)
    @ans.update_attributes(:score => value)
  end
end
```

I'm not very well versed with Rails view helpers and my solution might be slightly 2.3-ish.

Comment: Hello, @AdityaManohar. thanks. this won't indicate 'checked' where current data = the appropriate radio button.

Comment: i am getting the following error with your controller solution: "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
    params[:answer].each_pair |key,value| do"

Comment: I am attempting to correct some syntax issues so if someone else has this problem they'll see something that works. Overall, your answer got me there. Thanks!

Comment: @Jay The params[:answer] hash will contain the key-value pair only if a radio button is checked, ie: if Question 155 has been given a score of 5 then params[:answer] => { "155" => "5"} . The answer hash will not contain this key-value pair if the radio button is not checked - Hope this answers your query

Comment: @Jay Terribly sorry about the syntax error with the each_pair looping construct. And you're most welcome.